# How to find the hexadecimal address of temperature sensor?

Tags: hardware, temperature, fan, sensors

I'm trying to utilize a script (acerfand I believe) to my version of Acer Aspire One laptop to control fan on/off at certain temperatures. To work properly it needs values from temperature sensor. How can I find the hexadecimal address of temperature sensor? I've tried dmidecode, but I don't even know if it is correct place to search for it.

```
sub get_temp
{
    initialize_ioports();
    my $r = hex("xxx"); # Temperature
    my $temp = read_ec($r);
    close_ioports();
    return $temp;
}
```

Edit: somehow I found it! just in case if someone will be searching for this number, for acer aspire one 722 its: hex("0xB0").

Comment: Related - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fan_speed_control & https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed.

Comment: I think you should get away from the idea of accessing ioports via hex addresses in Linux, as this is DOS-style. Take a look at the `/dev` directory to get an impression on how Linux drivers work.

Comment: Note that there may not be "the hexadecimal address" of your temperature sensor, it may behind a wide variety of busses. Use lm-sensors to identify what sensors you have. There's also `fancontrol` which works with the lm-sensors infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried fancontrol (from arch wiki guide), but can't get lm-sersors to detect fan speed and pwmconfig gives me errors. Uh well, gues aao722 is not supported.

Comment: tried `acpi -V` ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the lm-sensors package installed. There are a number of useful commandline utilities included that can return that information, including isadump and sensors-detect that are part of that package.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the sensor has been connected via PCI bus.

First of all find your sensor directory using its driver (kernel module) name:

```
grep DRIVER /sys/bus/pci/devices/*/uevent
```

You'll see a batch of lines like this:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/uevent:DRIVER=pcieport
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:04.0/uevent:DRIVER=pcieport
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:11.0/uevent:DRIVER=ahci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:12.0/uevent:DRIVER=ohci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:12.2/uevent:DRIVER=ehci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:13.0/uevent:DRIVER=ohci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:13.2/uevent:DRIVER=ehci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/uevent:DRIVER=piix4_smbus
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.1/uevent:DRIVER=pata_atiixp
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.2/uevent:DRIVER=snd_hda_intel
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.5/uevent:DRIVER=ohci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/uevent:DRIVER=ohci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.2/uevent:DRIVER=ehci-pci
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.3/uevent:DRIVER=k10temp
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/uevent:DRIVER=nvidia
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.1/uevent:DRIVER=snd_hda_intel
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/uevent:DRIVER=r8169
```

One of this lines will contain name of your sensor kernel module - in the example above it's `k10temp` and the corresponding line is:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.3/uevent:DRIVER=k10temp
```

Thus, now we know sensor's directory - in the example this directory is:

```
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.3/
```

The file `device` from the directory contains hex-address of the sensor, so execute (for the example above):

```
cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:18.3/device
```

The output will be like this:

```
0x1703
```

If you can't recognize name of the sensor kernel module, just install `lm-sensors`, execute `sudo sensors-detect` and `sensors` afterwards - you'll find the name of kernel module easily since you'll see something like this for one of sensors:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
```

Comment: What if the sensor is not a PCI device? E.g. behind a I2C bus?

Comment: @dirkt Assume the OP author has PCI sensor. If another bus has been used, I'll add corresponding information. I have edited my answer and added assumption that PCI bus has been used.

Comment: The main problem is that the OP hasn't given *any* information about what kind of sensor(s) he has ... that's why the first thing to do is to use `lm-sensors` to find out what he has.

Comment: @Bob That is exactly what my output looks like. Anyway it's not working with acerfand script. Maybe you have same device? ;) Acer aspire one 722, did you manage to get control over fan? ;) Thank you for help.

Comment: @kshanowski Try this [https://github.com/RayfenWindspear/perl-acpi-fanspeed](https://github.com/RayfenWindspear/perl-acpi-fanspeed) or one of the available online `acer_ec.pl` scripts like this: [https://github.com/F0rth/acer_ec/blob/master/acer_ec.pl](https://github.com/F0rth/acer_ec/blob/master/acer_ec.pl). Just run something like this `sudo perl acer_ec.pl := 0x2F 0x3a` or `sudo perl acer_ec.pl := 0x2F 0x4a`

Comment: @Bob thanks, but your commands with acer_ec are not working.

`maciek@maciek-AO722:~/Downloads$ sudo perl acer_ec.pl := 0x2F 0x3a
[sudo] hasło użytkownika maciek:
REG[0x2f] == 0x4a
REG[0x2f] := 0x3a
REG[0x2f] == 0x3a
`
and nothing happens. And this first link seems to complicated. Thank you again, I'll live with it ;)